# using python script to run make

Tags: python, linux, makefile, build-process, busybox

i need to automate a way to create kernel root file system (based on busybox) and then build the kernel (and possibly third party loadable modules and applications.)
i am not sure what's the best way between these 2 methods:
creating a python script calls make files to build rootfile system/kernel/applicaiton.
creating main make file which then call other make files to build rootfile system/kernel/application.
for now, yocto linux is not an option.

can any suggest pro/cons between the 2 above methods?
thank you in advance.

Comment: In the first method, what would the Python script have to do?

Comment: either is fine. Make if more traditional, and more constrained -- try making it detect that one of the source files changed for example, not so easy in a huge project. Python is a hammer here - everything looks like a nail, definitely usable and used.

Comment: hi qarma. in the first method, python will just execute shells commands, mainly calling 'make -C' , etc...and copying binaries over to the root file system. i figure if i use python, i can support config file which allows custimization such as what to build.  but then with the makefile (second method), i can do the same thing using different targets. which one do you think would be more flexible and scalable and why? thank you in advance.